# Trouble getting parameters using route attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble implementing the routing in MVC 5. While debugging the expected url(e.g. `http://localhost/Download/Blog/1cf15fe6033a489a998556fedeab20a2/Test/1cd15fe6033a489a998556fedeab20a2`) causes the correct method on the Download controller to be called however the `did` and `fid` are always `null`.  What am I doing wrong?  I also tried removing the Download route and defining the routes in the controller with the following attributes:

```
[RoutePrefix("Download")] //on the controller
[Route("{action}/{did:guid}/Test/{fid:guid}")] //on the Blog Action
```

Here is what I have in my RouteConfig.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Download",
            url: "Download",
            defaults: new { controller = "Download", action = "Index" }
        );            

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { 
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional 
            }
        );
```

here is my controller:

```
[Route("{action}/{did}/Test/{fid}")]
public class DownloadController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Redirect(HandleBadResponse(webResponse));
    }

    [Route("{action}/{did}/Test/{fid}")]//nope
    public ActionResult Blog(HttpRequestMessage request,string did,string fid) 
    { 

        string server = Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];

        string pathStr = @"\\mypath\1cf15fe6033a489a998556fedeab20a2.xls";

        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathStr);
        string fileName = "test.txt";
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    }
```

Comment: You have the same route on your actual controller as you do on your action method. Is that a typo?

Comment: Its not a typo, though I did attempt the same thing I have listed without that route in my RouteConfig.cs file, neither way worked as I expected, `fid` and `did` were still `null` but the blog action was called on the download controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the expected result by adding the following to my `RouteConfig.cs` I placed this route at the top of my RegisterRoutes method, I think you should go from most detailed route to the least detailed route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DownloadBlogAttachment",
    url: "Download/Blog/{did}/fid/{fid}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Download", action = "Blog"}
);
```

I removed the Route attributes in my controller as well.